# Moving from original iPad to new iPad (2012): Is a cover like Apple's black one available for the new iPad?

Tags: accessories, case, ipad, smart-cover

I'm upgrading from the original iPad (2010) to the new iPad (2012).  I skipped the iPad 2 and the Smart Cover, so I don't have any compatible cover accessory for the new iPad.

I did try someone else's iPad 2 and Smart Cover before, and while I think the Smart Cover design is *clever*, it does little to protect the iPad from a fall, or the back from scratches.  And, while the magnets are strong, the Smart Cover *can* still separate; i.e. don't have a 4-year-old yank an iPad 2 by the Smart Cover and expect it to stay stuck!

What I would **really** like to shield my new iPad is something almost (but not quite) exactly like the cover I had for my original.  Of course I'm referring to **this:**

[image: Original Apple iPad black cover]

What I liked about the original black iPad case/cover is:

- it protected both front and back from scratches,
- it could be folded to stand in two orientations,
- the rubber-like material sticking out a bit at the edges made the case absorb some of the shock of a side-impact drop (helpful if you have a four-year-old .. though she's five now and is more careful!),
- it is tight fitting, and
- it could be cleaned easily.

I already tried putting my new iPad into the old iPad case/cover, and some things don't line up (power button, notably), and it's lacking the camera hole at the back, and it's no longer a tight fit since the new iPad is slimmer.

**Is there a third-party / aftermarket case almost exactly like the Apple one pictured above, but designed for the new iPad (2012)?** I'm hoping some company might have closely matched Apple's original design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Thought I should add this answer in case anybody comes across this page.)*

Since I asked my question originally, of course Apple introduced the **iPad Smart *Case***, which combines features from the original iPad case and the Smart Cover.  The Smart Case has a front much like the Smart Cover, but includes a backing part that better protects the iPad.  Reviews [here](http://reviews.cnet.com/cases-bags/apple-ipad-smart-case/4505-19214_7-35331778.html) and [here](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2405949,00.asp).  Here's what it looks like:

[image: Apple iPad Smart Case]

See it in the Apple Store online [here](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD454LL/A/ipad-smart-case-polyurethane-dark-gray).

Answer (score 2):

[Targus](http://www.targus.com/hk/ipad/index.asp) is advertising iPad 3 cases and one of their portfolio style cases may suit you.

Many iPad 2 cases will work with the new model. Although I haven't tested any of these on a new model iPad, you might consider:

[iLuv Portfolio Case with Stand](http://www.i-luv.com/product_detail.asp?idx=1563)

[Filemate Imagine series smart cover](http://www.walmart.com/ip/FileMate-Imagine-Series-iPad-2-Smart-Cover-Case-Magenta/19239241?findingMethod=rr)

Beyond that, a search for `iPad portfolio` will produce a multitude of choices.

Answer (score 0):

There are many iPad cases up on Amazon, some with the necessary cutouts for the cameras and controls of the iPad 2/3 and some without so be aware.

I have this one for my iPad2 and it's worked quite well. It's slim, has enough padding, has magnets that turn the screen on and off and allows all functionality.

[http://www.amazon.com/Genuine-Leather-Case-latest-generation/dp/B004TPG3ZS/ref=sr_1_3?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1331934880&sr=1-3](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004TPG3ZS)

The Case Crown cases are also nice but they're a bit thicker, mine's closer to the slim original Apple iPad case which my wife has on her iPad 1.